# How to add an HP (health) variable to a batch game

Tags: batch-file

So, I'm making a little batch CYOA style game, and I want to make an HP variable.
I used the code : `set /p hp=100` which just shows up as 100 in the file when it's run.

I also can't use the code `%hp%` to make it visible when I want it to be!
Anybody got any simple ways to add a variable that can't be changed by the file's user, but can be changed if the code calls for it, and can be shown when the `%hp%` command is typed in?

Comment: I'm a real amateur, so anything simple that's even vaguely similar is fine.

Comment: I do not really understand your question... Would you mind pasting your code to the question? This will bring much more clarity... Further I recommend reading the [tour] to have a look on this sites concept :) Welcome on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `/p`. That's for getting an answer back from the user, given a prompt string. Example:

```
set /p age=How old are you?
```

Whatever the user enters will get set to `age` and can be used with `%age%`.

In your case, just do `set hp=100`, and then you can say `echo HP: %hp%` to display it. Done.

Also, you can type `/?` (as in `set /?`) in cmd to get help for a command.